# Como mover os dois primeiros caracteres de uma palavra para o final dela?

Tags: python, string

Como posso mover os dois primeiros caracteres de uma palavra para o final dela? Por exemplo:

- `LUCAS` --> `CASLU`
- `casa` --> `saca`

Já tentei usar o `replace` tranformando em `list` e ler os dois primeiros caracteres `[0:2]`,`[-1:2]`

Comment: dica: uma string é um objeto sequencia que aceita indexação

Answer (score 1):

Conforme já comentado, você pode simplesmente acessar os indexes que você deseja e rearranja-los, por exemplo com lucas ficaria assim:

```
ss = "LUCAS"
print(ss[2:]+ss[0:2])
```

explicando, o `ss[2:]` significa que estou pegando a partir do segundo index até o final da palavra (sem nada depois dos dois pontos), ou seja o ***"CAS"***, em seguida concatenando `+` com o `ss[0:2]` que são as duas próximas letras a partir do index 0, o ***"LU"***. Resultado: "CASLU"